# Callback function GMaps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a problem with a callback function in Gmpaps programming.
I would insert some interest points on a map if they are within a specific distance range that the user selects from a menu on the web page.
My question is, if is possible to add some javascript code inside the callback function for example to alert the user with a popup message and so on...

```
 function callback(response, status) {             
              if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                  alert('Error was: ' + status);
              } else {
                var origins = response.originAddresses;
                var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
                var icon_2 = mapinfo[address_index_2-1][6];
                var results = response.rows[0].elements;
                     //alert(results[0].distance.value+" <= " +distance_selected);    
                      if(results[0].distance.value <= distance_selected){

                       // HERE I WOULD TO ADD SOME CODE e.g. AN ALERT 

                        geocoder.geocode({'address': mapinfo[address_index_2-1][1]+" "+mapinfo[address_index_2-1][2]+" "+mapinfo[address_index_2-1][3]+" "+mapinfo[address_index_2-1][4]}, 
                        function(results, status) {
                         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                              bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
                              map.fitBounds(bounds);
                              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                              map: map,
                              position: results[0].geometry.location,
                              icon: icon_2
                            });
                              map.setZoom(15);
                              map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                              google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'mouseover', function() {
                                            // Setting the content of the InfoWindow
                                            var filo_content = '<div id="info_map"><h3>' + f_title + '</h3></h5><a href="'+ f_link +'"><h5>Leggi...</h5></a>' + '</div>';                                                
                                            infowindow.setContent(filo_content);                                             
                                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                            }); 

                              markersArray.push(marker);   
                          } 
                          else {
                            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: "
                              + status);
                          } // chiusura else

                        });

                      }  //chiusura if controllo distanza

                    }

              } // chiusura callback
```

Comment: Why not, that's the only purpose of a callback-function, and you've already an alert there! What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Yes but the alert don't work :( for example if I set a global variable into the callback function the result otuside is undefined...

Comment: It is best practice to use any variables set in the callback function, in the function itself.  They are't valid until it runs (as you discovered).

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I have solved.. the problem was an else if where I called another callback function with the same name...